# Pass data to v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

How can I pass index from option to v-model in select?

```
<select v-model="selectedItem">
    <option v-for="item, index" in list" :index="index">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

`selectedItem` just store item, without index. How can I  get the option index, like `selectedItem.index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Bind the `option` tag value to the `index`:

```html
<select v-model="selectedItem">
    <option v-for="item, index" in list" :value="index">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

The `selectedItem` will then be the selected item's index, you don't need to have both the item and its index at the same time as it is redundant:

```js
const item = this.list[this.selectedItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index to be stored on `selectedItem.index` then you have to make the `v-model` be `selectedItem.index`

Other than that you need to change [`:index` to `:value`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#example-6) and fix your syntax issue with your [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#example-1)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedItem: {},
    list: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedItem.index">
    <option v-for="(item, index) in list" :value="index">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
  <pre>{{selectedItem}}</pre>
</div>
```